# POSTing a Blob with FormData via jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I've seen this question asked many times, but as much as I try, I'm still seeing no results:

How can I append a Blob to form data and POST it via jquery?

```
var reader = FileReader(); 
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
reader.onload = function() {
    var slice = reader.result.slice(0,100, {type: "application/octet-stream"});

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("blobData", slice); // I have verified via console.log(slice) that this has data
    formdata.append("blobName", "Photo");

    send(formdata);
}

function send(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/upload",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,    
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

All the non-blob key/values are in the request, and even the blob's key... but not the blob data.

[image: Missing data]

Interestingly, when I post using Firefox instead of Chrome, I get a little bit of data up there.. but not much (this should be up to 2 MB worth of data... it's 7 bytes)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently encountered this exact problem and have the solution.

The core issue is that the value of `reader.result` passed to `reader.onload` by `readAsBinaryString` is a string, not a blob. Sounds obvious really but I also assumed I was working with a blob. Since String and Blob objects both have a slice method the variable `slice`, whilst set with data that looks like binary data, is still just a string. The String.slice() method works exactly the same as the Blob.slice() method and just ignores the third parameter, which is why you don't notice what's really happening.

According to the [FormData spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) any value that is not a Blob or File object is converted to a string. It appears that the `slice` string is being truncated at the first non-ASCII character (I'm just guessing as to the exact reason, but the important point is that the string is definitely being truncated when it's appended to `formdata`).

The solution is to convert `reader.result` into a blob first:

```
reader.onload = function() {
    var blob = new Blob([reader.result]), 
        slice = blob.slice(0,100, {type: "application/octet-stream"});

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("blobData", slice);
    formdata.append("blobName", "Photo");

    send(formdata);
}
```

(The array is a requirement of the Blob constructor).

Now `slice` is a blob, since the Blob.slice() method returns a Blob object, and can be appended to `formdata` without being mangled by string conversion.